# PHP vs. JSP performance: is the compiled vs. interpreted argument even relevant to this issue?

Tags: php, performance, jsp

PHP is interpreted. JSPs are compiled. Yet the PHP interpreter seems tightly coupled with Apache (using mod_php). The JSPs are compiled, but it's bytecode...yet the java runtime is highly optimized...yet there is the Tomcat container and mod_jk sitting in between Apache and the runtime.

Lots of things to consider, of course. Has anyone benchmarked these two configs? Anybody have some real-world data or experiences concerning performance, whether it is a simple site, or complex, under various (preferably heavy) loads?

Any thoughts?

For best performance should I code it all in C++ using a CGI gateway? (ha ha just kidding)

Comment: PHP is compiled into bytecode aswell. The only difference is, that PHP recompiles the file on every request. If you install a bytecode cache, then it basically works the way jsp does.

I would really like to see some real world benchmarks aswell.

Comment: No, for *best* performance (without going insane) write it all in **C** using FastCGI. ;-)  Seriously, though, remember that if you're using Sun's Java implementation, even the bytecode gets compiled to machine code (HotSpot is a JIT-compiler). http://java.sun.com/javase/technologies/hotspot/

Comment: Just a genera comment on the "best performance" question: It might be best to write the bulk of your code in whatever makes you most productive and bring in the zippy for the real bottlenecks.

Answer (score 2):

PHP is compiled into bytecode also. To prevent this from happening on every request, install APC. This will cache the compilation so it doesnt have to happen every time.

You might find [this](http://shootout.alioth.debian.org/u32q/) interesting.

Comment: +1 Might want to expand on "this" a bit, people don't like links with no explanation of where they link to. Interesting link, btw.

Comment: What is interesting about a link to "Server Not Found" ??